# How to run a method in a unit Test only after a method in my application has finished?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I want to test a value in my unit test. This value is set in a method which is called by a button click in the main application. I'd like to have code like this in the unit test:

```
after ButtonClick().isFinished{ //insert working code here?
    TestMethod();
}

public void TestMethod(){
    Assert.AreEqual(value, "foo");
}
```

In the main application there is code like this:

```
protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
    value="foo";
}
```

I don't want to change `ButtonClick` if possible because I don't want to mingle application code and test code.

P.S. This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so please cut me some slack for my noob ways :)

Comment: There's no `methodCalledByButtonClick ` in your question?

Comment: I think your question stems from a misunderstanding on how to write unit tests. Your `methodCalledByButtonClick` will have some input, and some expected output. So, instead of relying on some button being clicked, you should mock the inputs you're expecting, and assert the consequences of `methodCalledByButtonClick` being called.

Comment: @canton7 You are of course right, I edited my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just invoke the method the following way

```
[Test]
public void testMe() {
  ButtonClick(this, EventArgs.Empty)
  Assert.AreEqual(value, "foo")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution!